# Android: Sliding button container widget

Tags: android, widget, slider, containers

I am running out of room on my app for buttons, so I want to stick them into some sort of sliding container, like the one at the top of the Astro File Manager app. How do I go about doing this? I've Googled this and can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your buttons in a scrollview, that is exactly how its done in the contacts popup in 2.x devices.

Comment: that could work as well, depends on the look you are going for.  The sliding container menu in Astro is a horizontal scrollview

Comment: Ah, and I was so sure it was the Gallery widget!

Thanks so much for the answer!